# how the garbage collection and reference count works hand in hand in Xamarin

Tags: ios, memory-management, xamarin.ios, garbage-collection, automatic-ref-counting

Xamarin has it own memory management tool called Garbage Collector as it uses C#.

When we develop iOS application reference count comes into picture.

I really couldn't understand on how these two memory management techniques work hand in hand.

Because some object in can get garbage collected while its holding on the Objective object causing the memory leak,dangling pointer etc.. the same applies vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Unmanaged objects (Objects inherited from NSObject) are not managed by the GC.
Xamarin's GC can not handle unmanaged objects circular references,handling a circular references requires a weak reference.
You have to be careful when you create references between managed and unmanaged objects,especially in Lambda.

See [Xamarin iOS memory leaks everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532870/xamarin-ios-memory-leaks-everywhere)