# Should I keep the C# reference to an NSData object around until I know for sure that an underlying native call in iOS has finished using it or not?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, garbage-collection, maui

I'm dealing with C# bindings to iOS and I was curious about certain aspects of parameter-passing. Assume we have the following piece of code:

```cs
            public void BeginNativeCallFromCsharpToIOS(byte[] data)
            {
                var nsData = NSData.FromArray(data);

                 // non blocking    takes 1 minute to complete
                _theNativeIosObject.BeginNativeCallToIosHere(nsData);
            }
```

I'm wondering whether in this code-sample the nsData variable will be auto-disposed by the C# garbage collector before the underlying iOS operation (which is asynchronous) manages to fully complete in iOS-native-mode.

Because if nsData does indeed get garbage collected above then I'm afraid that the underlying native ns-array object will be eligible to corruption (and potentially cause the entire app crash).

If that's the case I was thinking of refactoring the code to be a bit more cautious around the disposal of _nsData:

```cs
private NSData _nsData;
public void BeginNativeCallFromCsharpToIOS(byte[] data)
{
     _nsData = NSData.FromArray(data);

     // non blocking    takes 1 minute to complete
     _theNativeIosObject.BeginNativeCallToIosHere(nsData);
}

// later on when we are notified that the native call has completed
public void Cleanup()
{
     _nsData?.Dispose();
     _nsData = null;
}
```

Is this really necessary? Any ideas?

Comment: About this you can check these cases: [how the garbage collection and reference count works hand in hand in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736318/how-the-garbage-collection-and-reference-count-works-hand-in-hand-in-xamarin), [Xamarin iOS memory leaks everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532870/xamarin-ios-memory-leaks-everywhere).